# Magento 2 override template problem

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I need to override a template file `\Magento\Customer\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml` in my custom module.

According to [Magento's document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html). I know that creating a custom theme module can fit my need, but I want to know other than creating a custom theme module, are there some other methods for overriding a template file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the customer module to customize the register template. You have to create the new custom module and inside that module's `etc/module.xml` file, you have to set:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Package_Module" setup_version="2.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi Rocky, could you explain a little more about what this is doing and why it's needed?

Comment: if you want to override contact module form.phtml, you have to create new custom module and inside module root etc/module.xml file you have to define your core module name inside sequence tag. Its useful for override core module template.

Comment: That gives no more information than your answer did. What does the sequence tag do and how does it work?

Comment: <sequence> element in the module.xml file is used to define the load order of dependencies.you can getting more info about sequence tag from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/modules/mod_depend.html